# Netmask/ip-address lookup on BSD/OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, network-programming, bsd

How do I do ip-address/netmask etc. lookup on OS X (or BSD) using the python standard library function. I'm in the middle of a process and can't make my script working on Mac. On the Linux machine, it's pretty simple:

```
ifname = "eth0"
SIOCGIFNETMASK = 0x891b
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), SIOCGIFNETMASK, struct.pack('256s', ifname))[20:24])
```

It returns the the netmask, for example. On OS X, I get `Operation not supported on socket` error:

```
>>> import socket, fcntl, struct
>>> ifname = "en0"
>>> SIOCGIFNETMASK = 0x891b
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), SIOCGIFNETMASK, struct.pack('256s', ifname))[20:24])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket
>>>
```

Looks like SIOCGIFNETMASK, SIOCGIFADDR etc. offsets are different in BSD/OS X system. Any idea how do I get around this issue? Already found a couple of posts on the same sort of issue but didn't get a definitive answer. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. cheers!!

Comment: Interesting svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=230207

Answer (score 0):

I don't have BSD system to try but hope it should work

```
socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM), 35099, struct.pack('256s', iface))[20:24])
```

Comment: I already tried `35099` but the same error on OS X. thanks anyway!!

Comment: Did you try SIOCSIFNETMASK 0x891c ?

Comment: also did you try SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_DGRAM? just curious

Comment: Just tried `0x891c` and it doesn't work either; failed with the exactly same error. Looks like `SIOCSIFNETMASK` is not the way to go with BSD [sub]system. Cheers!!

Comment: And the same with `SOCK_DGRAM` - fails with the very same error. Thanks!

Comment: Any other suggestion(s) from any one? Cheers!!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this on BSD?  Or did you take another approach?